# Angular Promises - Jumping from the success to the failure callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I feel like I may be doing something that Promises weren't designed to do, but here we go, this is what I'd like to do:

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanA.json').then(
    function success( response ) {
        if ( response.data.isAllGood ) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
        else {
            // TODO HERE! Call the failure function!
        }
    },
    function failure() {
        $http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanB.json').then(
            function planBsuccess( response ) {
                $scope.myData = response.data;
            }
        );
    }
).then(function doOtherStuff() {});
```

This works as expected if, for example the `PlanA` endpoint returns a 404 or 500... but if it succeeds, but has bad data (eg, `isAllGood` is false), then I'd like it to get to the failure callback. Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried calling `$q.defer().reject` and returning that promise, however that just calls the failure callback for `doOtherStuff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it. Its bad design. Here is a much simpler solution:

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanA.json').then(
    function success( response ) {
        if ( response.data.isAllGood ) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
        else {
             foo();
        }
    },
    function failure() {
        foo();
    }
).then(function doOtherStuff() {});

foo = function(){
  $http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanB.json').then(
        function planBsuccess( response ) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
   );
};
```

That being said, I think even this is abusing how `$http` was designed. I would instead do something like

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanA.json').then(
    function success( response ) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
    },
    function failure() {
        trueFailureFunc();
    }
).then(validateData());

validateData = function(){
    if ( response.data.isAllGood ) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
    }
     else {
        getDataFromOtherSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I basically wrapped your second one in a function that returned a promise itself, and when it `resolved`, I called by `doOtherStuff`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an easy way to do it. You just have to chain the failure callback *after* the success callback, not next to it - see [When is .then(success, fail) considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for a more detailed explanation.

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanA.json').then(function success(response) {
    if (response.data.isAllGood) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    } else {
        return $q.reject(); // fail this promise
    }
}).catch(function failure() { // and handle it here (also errors originating from $http)
    return $http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanB.json').then(function planBsuccess(response) {
//  ^^^^^^ don't forget to wait with doOtherStuff for plan B
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
}).then(function doOtherStuff() {});
```

or even better, avoiding the code duplication of the `$scope` assignment:

```
$http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanA.json').then(function validate(response) {
    if (response.data.isAllGood)
        return response;
    else
        throw new Error("noGoodData");
}).catch(function failure() {
    return $http.get('/api/endpoint/PlanB.json');
}).then(function success(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    return doOtherStuff();
});
```